# IV regression and instrument validity: help with interpretation

Tags: regression, stata, instrumental-variables

It is my first time working with IV regression and I need some help with understanding the process. Specifically, I am looking at the effect of female presidents/prime ministers on health/education expenditure. Following a paper by Chen(2020), I use the electoral rule as an instrumental variable for the the gender of the leader. The problem is, when I run the baseline regression in Stata:

`xtivreg2 educationexpenditurelag (male=majoritarianrule) i.year, fe robust first`

the p-value of the F test of excluded instruments is not significant (first stage) , but once I include my control variables it becomes significant.

Does that mean that my instrument is not appropriate since the baseline regression has a not significant relationship between instrumental and instrumented variable?

Comment: If I haven't explained clearly enough, please let me know

Comment: I think this is perfectly fine to use the F stat from the specification with controls, assuming there is nothing peculiar about them. Unfortunately one needs to have some sense of the literature and the setting to figure out if they are in fact peculiar.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov thank you very much for your feedback since I need this for my Masters Thesis! I used controls suggested in the aforementioned paper and other lit. such as population, type of government, log GDP, ethnic fractionalisation, regime stability, oil rents etc. 
So, just to check again, if Sanderson-Windmeijer multivariate F test of excluded instruments & Underidentification test (Kleibergen-Paap rk LM statistic) are fine with controls, then it is fine to assume the instrument can be used even if the same cannot be said for the baseline regression?